# Sharpkeys program alternative for linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint, keymap

Sorry it's the second time that I post this question because till now I can't found solution :

My keyboard is damaged, the keyboard key [é] is always pressed and it prevents me from working on LinuxMint Distribution .
(writing in terminal is impossible !! I can't type any things always the é button interfere and it's chaos(èèèèèèèèèèè.....) )

I am looking for something a little more noob than Xmodmap or xev to get my keyboard right ??

Is there any GUI apps that I can download from their app stores or software manager?

Comment: Some keyboards cost as little as 5€, is it really worth it?

Comment: no Jan I talk about an integrated keyboard on my laptop. Even if I work with an external usb keyborad the problem persists

Comment: Oh, silly me. Hadn't thought of that. However, even those can be replaced - if you're not too bad with a screwdriver. Should find one around 50€ ...

Comment: Oh, silly me !! sorry but I don't mean that .

Comment: If it is damaged and it always is stuck down it should go beep beep  beep ..... when it boots (I had a keyboard problem when my pc had Windows and it beeped. I think the beep comes from the BIOS)

Answer (score 1):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 123 = 0x0000"
```

with the *123* being replaced with the keycode of your hung key.

Use `xev` to identify the keycode for your broken key. Also look at its man page, it's a good quick reference, too.

[ArchWiki has a good description for xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this link is useful : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/xbindkeys

As a hack, we could use a global shortcut program like Xbindkeys, and bind the é key to /bin/true, which does nothing.

XbindKeys has a graphical interface via apt://xbindkeys-config